# Failing to Start MariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04 - missing SSH key or bad login information?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, configuration, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

I have just installed MariaDB on a new Ubuntu 18.04 box. When I attempt to start the server, I get this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

When I type "journalctl -xe", this seems to be relevant:

```
Apr 05 11:21:00 oddswatch sshd[26131]: Failed password for root from [IP ADDRESS] port 41884 ssh2
Apr 05 11:21:01 oddswatch sshd[26131]: Connection closed by authenticating user root [IP ADDRESS] port 41884 [preauth]
Apr 05 11:21:01 oddswatch sshd[26133]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Apr 05 11:21:03 oddswatch sshd[26133]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=[IP ADDRESS]  user=root
Apr 05 11:21:03 oddswatch sudo[26135]:    jason : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jason ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Apr 05 11:21:03 oddswatch sudo[26135]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by jason(uid=0)
```

The error message is not being able to load /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key. I have consulted google and generated and re-generated this damn thing a dozen different ways and that message doesn't go away.

I'm not sure that's my issue though. It appears to be trying to connect root@IP_ADDRESS rather than root@localhost. When I try to log-in with root@IP_ADDRESS (e.g. mysql -u root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p) it doesn't work (i.e. when I log-in, it says access denieD) but mysql -u root -p works just fine. Could it be trying to access the the server in a way that it can't authenticate?

And in any case how do I verify the password? I haven't entered the password anywhere so I'm not sure why there is a failed password.

Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: The information you have presented is not likely relevant. The information you want is likely elsewhere in the journalctl -xe output. It will almost certainly reference mysql and not ssh.

Comment: Please describe how have you installed MariaDB. Have you followed some tutorial? Post the link of it. In Ubuntu 18 you don't use init.d, you use systemd, `sudo systemctl status mariadb`. As user568220 wrote, you gave irrelevant information, about sshd service.

Comment: @dexter and user568220 - thanks for pointing out that I was looking at the wrong spot. It appears as though there were maybe some ghost processes that prevented MariaDB from starting? I'm not really sure but killing them off I was able to successfully start the process. Thanks again!